# Using defer to implement jQuery-ready-like function in the same HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to remove my jQuery and I need to replace `$(function() { ... });` with something similar. I have seen people use the new HTML property `defer` but they use it to call another script rather than calling codes in the the same HTML source. How can I use `defer` to implement the same `ready` feature in my HTML code without calling another script?

```html
<div style="margin-top: 100px">.</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
<script defer>alert('hi')</script>
<div>BBBB</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you cannot defer a script body code, only its source file. How does your question relates to the provided HTML code? What is your problem exactly? PS: [Window/DOMContentLoaded_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, how to implement ready function? Look at the comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010 . Seems `DOMContentLoaded` is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Just write `<script>` tag in the before `<body>`, so first will be loaded HTML DOM, and then only script.

Comment: @NNL993, not an attractive solution nor practical in every scenario. jQuery ready works flawlessly.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is your cleanest option for inline scripts (which you shouldn't use in the first place). I don't think that 6 year old comment is any relevant these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have three standard options at your disposal, two being explicit, and one being implicit and relying on how the browser parses the document (top-down, element by element):

1. `defer`. Adding the `defer` attribute to a script tag results in the script execution being delayed until immediately before `DOMContentLoaded` *would fire* (when the DOM is parsed), and makes sure `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't actually fire before the full script has been executed. **Please note that `defer` must not be used when the `src` attribute is missing (that is, it's only available for external scripts).**
2. `DOMContentLoaded` listener (or `readyStateChange` listener if you enjoy complicating things).
3. Adding your `script` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Please note that scripts that have `type="module"` are automatically deferred.

Personally, I stopped using jQuery around 2015, and since that, have been working with `DOMContentLoaded` ever since, with not a single issue in all those years.